# How can I use Code Contracts to ensure that a non-blank, non-null val should always be returned from a method?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

This code:

```
private static char GetBarcodeChecksumWithLegacyCode(string barcodeWithoutCzechSum)
{
    Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(barcodeWithoutCzechSum));
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result != null);
    . . .
```

...doesn't compile ("*Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and ''*").

This fails the same way:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn != null);
```

How can I enforce the necessity of the method returning a result using Code Contracts?

### UPDATE

If I do this:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<char>() != '');
```

...it fails with, "Empty character literal"

So is this the way to test for the returned char val being both non-null and non-empty:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<char>() != null && Contract.Result<char>().ToString() != string.Empty);
```

...or does the null check suffice?

BTW, trying to use ValueAtReturn instead of Result gives me "*No overload for method 'ValueAtReturn' takes 0 arguments*"

### UPDATE 2

This code:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null && Contract.Result<String>() != string.Empty);
```

fails with:

*In method BarcodeCzechDigitTester.Form1.GetBarcodeChecksumWithLegacyCode(System.String): Detected a call to Result with 'System.String', should be 'System.Char'.*

(twice) Also: "*The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccrewrite.exe" "@BarcodeCzechDigitTesterccrewrite.rsp"" exited with code 2.*"

...but changing the code to this works:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<char>() != null && Contract.Result<char>().ToString() != string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have it like:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
```

Comment: Or presumably, in my case (they both compile): Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<char>() != null);

Comment: `char` can't have null.

Comment: Then why does it compile?

Comment: It will compile but will give you a warning, since this would be unnecessary. Warning would be: `The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'`

Comment: Since your result can't be null why have the contract in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

char is value type, it cannot be null.

char is not collection (like string or array), it cannot be empty.

If your method is returning bar code check-sum numeric character, then your contract can check for check-sum character values like this:

```
Contract.Ensures ( '0' <= Contract.Result<char>() && Contract.Result<char>() <= '9' );
```